# How to stop the url sending(setGridParam) request in Jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I have created external three checkbox.

First I check the Male check box, sending the request to backend,response taking time 30 to 50 Sec.But suddenly I press Female checkbox, not send the female value parameter to backend.

SO I want to stop sending the request. Send new request with new parameters.

*The Previous request finished after send the new request.*

When I check ‘All’, it takes 2-3 minutes to fetch the response. Until the response is got, no other parameter can be set/sent.
For example: If I check ‘All’, I can’t send the parameter for uncheck/check ‘Male’ or ‘Female’ until I get the response for ‘All’.
I use setGridParam and get the data in JSON format.

it takes 2-3 minutes to fetch

```
$("#sex,#age).change(function() {

var sexVal=$("#sex").val();
//sexVal values are Male, Female and All

var listURL='localset.php?mode=yes&sex='+sexVal;
$("#list451").jqGrid("clearGridData", true);
jQuery("#list451").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url : listURL,mtype:'POST',datatype:'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid");

});


jQuery("#list451").jqGrid({
    url: 'localset.php?mode=yes',
    datatype: "json",
    height: 255,
    width: 600,
    colNames: ['Index', 'Name', 'Code', 'N Name', 'C Name'],
    colModel: [{
            name: 'item_id',
            index: 'item_id',
            width: 65,
            sorttype: 'integer',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'le', 'lt', 'gt', 'ge']
            }
        }, {
            name: 'name',
            index: 'name',
            width: 150,
            sorttype: 'string',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: [cn]
            }
        }, {
            name: 'code',
            index: 'code',
            width: 150,
            sorttype: 'string',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en']
            }
        }, {
            name: 'sex',
            index: 'sex',
            width: 150,
            sorttype: 'string',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: [cn]
            }
        }, {
            name: 'c_name',
            index: 'c_name',
            width: 150,
            sorttype: 'string',
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: [cn]
            }
        },
        rowNum: 50,
        rowTotal: 200,
        rowList: [20, 30, 50],
        loadonce: true,
        mtype: "POST",
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 40,
        gridview: true,
        pager: '#pager451',
        sortname: 'item_id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        caption: "External Check box Demo"
    }); jQuery("#list451").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    searchOperators: true
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear enough. What exact scenario you have (step by step)? What behavior you want to implement? If you want to send `sex` parameter to the server you can use `postData: { sex: function () { return $("#sex").val(); }}`. In the case every request to the server will contains the current value of the `"#sex"` control. You you want load grid only once you can use `loadonce: true`. You can disable `"#sex"` control any time by usage `$("#sex").prop("disabled", true)`. There are many scenarios, but it's unclear what you want to implement.

Comment: When I check ‘All’, it takes 2-3 minutes to fetch the response. Until the response is got, no other parameter can be set/sent.
For example: If I check ‘All’, I can’t send the parameter for uncheck/check ‘Male’ or ‘Female’ until I get the response for ‘All’.
I use setGridParam and get the data in JSON format.

it takes 2-3 minutes to fetch

Comment: I have more options externally like check box, drop down, text box. Its complex to change the code and render the JSON format code.Thats why i use the setGridParam.

Comment: You write about "check/uncheck", but you have probably `<select>` with 3 values `"Male"`, `"Female"` and `"All"`. Is it so? Moreover you describes that your server (`localset.php`) is very slow. But I still don't understand your question. What you want to ask? What you want to implement?

Comment: If the loading from the server is slow and you have not so much total rows of data than you can just load the data for `sex="all"` and filter the data **locally** without changing `datatype` to `'json'`.

Comment: The user can change the ‘options’ only when the response for the previous request is fetched. So, if the user wants just ‘male’ related records, the user has to wait till ‘all’ related records are fetched. Is there any way by which I can stop ‘All’ (which is taking time) request 
and make ‘male’ request immediately?

Comment: when user selects female check box then it sent to Server , before the Response received from the Back end 
user selects the male check box.
So i want to cancel the Previous Request for fetching the female records and Need to sent the New request to the Server.

Expected scenario is to process the Latest request from the User.It should not wait for Pending previous Request(Response not received)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question you want to cancel previous Ajax request. You should do two things for it:

1. disable the overlay created at the beginning of the Ajax request
2. execute `abort` method of the pending Ajax request.

To remove overlay and to reset `$("#list451")[0].grid.hDiv.loading` used by jqGrid for internal purpose you can just call `$("#list451")[0].endReq()`.

You can use `loadBeforeSend` callback for example to cache `jqXHR` of the last Ajax request. You need just save the first parameter of the callback in a variable defied in the outer scope. You can call `abort()` method to abort the previous request.